# I keep getting this error when I run this program. I have tried everything I can think of and it is still not working

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying this NCAA basketball prediction program and I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/chromeos/removable/JACKS JUNK/Chatbot_2/sports_predict.py", line 17, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
  File "/home/jackmdavis06/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2116, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/home/jackmdavis06/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 237, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/home/jackmdavis06/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2258, 4148]
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sportsreference.ncaab.teams import Teams
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

FIELDS_TO_DROP = ['away_points', 'home_points', 'date', 'location',
                  'losing_abbr', 'losing_name', 'winner', 'winning_abbr',
                  'winning_name', 'home_ranking', 'away_ranking']


teams = Teams()


dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = dataset.drop(FIELDS_TO_DROP, 1).dropna().drop_duplicates()
y = dataset[['home_points', 'away_points']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

parameters = {'bootstrap': False,
                'min_samples_leaf': 3,
                'n_estimators': 50,
                'min_samples_split': 10,
                'max_features': 'sqrt',
                'max_depth': 6}
model = RandomForestRegressor(**parameters)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.predict(X_test).astype(int), y_test)
```

I followed the guide on this website:

https://towardsdatascience.com/predict-college-basketball-scores-in-30-lines-of-python-148f6bd71894

I tweaked the code a little bit to make it work faster, so I tried running the original code and the original code only and I got the same exact error. Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you have to treat y and X equally before splitting. When you do dropna() and drop_duplicates() only on X you are changing the size of that dataframe, but y remains in the original size.

Comment: So do I drop_duplicates() and dropna() for the Y?

Comment: I'm not sure you should do this because I do not know how is this dataset structured, but if you do this procedure for X, you have to do it for y too.

Answer (score 1):

You dropped nulls and duplicates for X, but not y.
If you `print(X.shape[0], len(y))`, you will see that they have different values.

You should do something like:

```py
#...
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# drop nulls and dublicates
# use fields to keep for your analysis both features and target
# e.g. FIELDS_TO_KEEP = ['a', 'b' ...]
dataset = dataset[FIELDS_TO_KEEP].dropna().drop_duplicates()

# get your feature X, target y
X = dataset[FIELDS_THAT_ARE_FEATURES]
y = dataset[['home_points', 'away_points']]

# ...
```